# Type 'Like' has no subscript member?

Tags: swift, xcode, class, subscript

I have 2 custom classes. And I'm trying to assign the value of `likes` dictionary from `Like` class to the value of `likes` property of the `Post` class. But I get the:

> Type 'Like' has no subscript member

```
class Like {
    var likes: Dictionary<String, Any>?
    var userUid: String?
}

extension Like {

    static func transfromLikes(dictionary: [String : Any]) -> Like {

        let like = Like()

        like.likes = dictionary["likes"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
        like.userUid = dictionary["userUid"] as? String

        return like
    }
}

class Post {

   var id           : String?
   var title        : String?
   var content      : String?
   var userUid      : String?
   var isLiked      : Bool? = false
   var likes        : Like?
   var likesCount   : Int?
}

extension Post {

    static func transformDataToImagePost (dictionary: [String : Any], key: String) -> Post {
        let post = Post()
        let like = Like()
        post.id        = key
        post.userUid   = dictionary["userUid"] as? String
        post.title     = dictionary["title"] as? String
        post.likes     = like.likes?["likes"] as? Like

        if let currentUserId = Api.Users.CURRENT_USER?.uid {
            if post.likesCount != nil {
                post.isLiked = post.likes?[currentUserId] != nil // this is the error
            }
        }
        return post
    }
```

Comment: `post.likes?.likes[currentUserId]`

Comment: Ugh, yes! That was it. Please add it as an answer so I can approve it and close the question! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post.likes` is of type `Like?`.  You need to add the property `likes` to that before subscripting it:

```
post.isLiked = post.likes?.likes?[currentUserId] != nil
```